# Binary XML file: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I know this is a common sort of question but I have tried most of all the solution available on net but it is still not working, so please help.

I am trying to create a navigation drawer in my project I am facing the logcat error on very first run that `"android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file: Error inflating class fragment"`.

I have created 4 files:

1. the main activity
2. its layout
3. Drawer activity
4. its layout

The code is below:

1) the mainactivity which I have named Home

```
package GJ.helpinghand;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Home extends FragmentActivity {

private ListView con;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


    Drawer drawer_instance = (Drawer) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.drawer_frag);

    drawer_instance.setUp(R.id.drawer_frag,(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)); 

    /*Drawer_try drawer_instance = (Drawer_try) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.drawer_frag);

    drawer_instance.setUp(R.id.drawer_frag,(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    */
    con = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.content);

    final String[] info = new String[] { "Android List View", "Adapter implementation" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.listlay,R.id.title, info);
    con.setAdapter(adap);

    con.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String to = info[position];
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), to , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
   }
```

2. The XML for main Activity which is causing error:

   ```
   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context="GJ.helpinghand.Home" >

   <RelativeLayout 
       android:id="@+id/core"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView1"
           android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:text="@string/file"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

       <ListView
           android:id="@+id/content"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
           android:divider="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />

   </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment 
       android:id="@+id/drawer_frag"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       class="com.fragment.NavigationDrawerFragment"
       tools:layout="@layout/fragment_drawer" />
   ```

3) the drawer's java file:

```
package GJ.helpinghand;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Drawer extends Fragment {


private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";
private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerListView;
private View mFragmentContainerView;

private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

public Drawer() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState
                .getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
        mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }

    // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
    selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of
    // actions in the action bar.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_drawer, container, false);
    mDrawerListView
            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    selectItem(position);
                }
            });
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar()
            .getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1, new String[] {
                    getString(R.string.title_section1),
                    getString(R.string.title_section2),
                    getString(R.string.title_section3), }));
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
}


public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
    return mDrawerLayout != null
            && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
}


public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
    // opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);

    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_drawer,
    R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls
                                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to
                // prevent auto-showing
                // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true)
                        .commit();
            }

            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls
                                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce
    // them to the drawer,
    // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
    if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
    if (mDrawerListView != null) {
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
    if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(
                "Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar.
    // See also
    // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the
    // action bar.
    if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
        showGlobalContextActionBar();
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to
 * show the global app 'context', rather than just what's in the current
 * screen.
 */

private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
}

private ActionBar getActionBar() {
    return  getActivity().getActionBar();
}

/**
 * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must
 * implement.
 */
public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
    /**
     * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
     */
    void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
}
}
```

4) The XML for Drawer:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="GJ.helpinghand.Drawer$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</FrameLayout>
```

5) And the Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="GJ.helpinghand"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <permission android:name="WRRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></permission>    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".Drawer"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_drawer" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Move `fragment` xml inside RelativeLayout

Comment: xmlns:android I don't see this attribute in your main xml

Comment: Do you have any message like Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException ? If yes then please provide those lines

Comment: yeah, I guess in editing that part was deleted. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML for Main Activity should be look like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/core"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/file"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:divider="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />

</RelativeLayout>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/drawer_frag"
        android:name="com.fragment.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In the fragment change `class` attribute to `android:name` as `android:name="com.fragment.NavigationDrawerFragment"`

Also there is a mistake in `onCreateView` method of `Drawer` because here you are inflating a layout named `fragment_drawer` and forcibly casting `FrameLayout` to a `ListView` which will lead to inflation error

to resolve this add a `ListView` in your `drawer xml` as given below

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="GJ.helpinghand.Drawer$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Now map this `ListView` to your `DrawerListView` in code as below in `onCreateView` method

```
View drawer= inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_drawer, false);
mDrawerListView = (ListView)drawer.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
.....Your code
return drawer;
```

Hope this will help you, if you find this helpful please mark it as answer.
All the Best!!!

Comment: Hey, both the points you pointed out here was considered by me already. 1) the XML of MainActivity is same like the one u mentioned, it was like i might have not copied it completely while posting it. Sorry about that.                2) I know this ListView Stuff was causing problem and that's why I also tried running the app after adding this portion in comments.

Comment: @GauravJindal Ok then you can create NavigationDrawerActivity from the Studio it will provide you a running sample of Drawer Layout and then you can modify it as you want.

Comment: I started in that way only...and this methods in my drawer file are copied from such a file only. But what I think is the real problem lies in the MainActivity(i.e. Home in our case) or its XML file. Please let me know if you note something wrong there. BTW Thanks for taking your precious time to give reply.